# How to open an aspx page using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to know how to display an aspx page in a popup using jquery

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a partial instead of a full page most likely and then use the get method as outlined here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax.  Then you can put the contents of your get request into a jqModal modal window as defined by this page: http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

Comment: What is the best way to perform a GET with ASP and jQuery? Would you create a handler to return JSON, would you use a [WebMethod] that returns JSON [ I'm biased to use JSON ;) ] or what other methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

or  this : 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1774770.aspx/1